# Pdf videos on mobile phone

Tags: android, video, pdf

I put a video in my pdf with Acrobat and there I can watch my video. But if I open the pdf on my mobile, I can't watch the video, I only see an image. Is there a way to watch videos of a pdf in a mobile? I have a samsung J5.

Answer (score 1):

To play enmbedded audio and videos in video you can also try [Foxit pdf lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxit.mobile.pdf.lite) and its free.

As from the description mentioned it has various other features as well

```
• View, manage, and annotate PDF files
• Reflow PDF files for easy viewing
• Support multiple tab view (for tablets only)
• Rename, move, copy or delete PDF file(s)
• Annotate, stamp, and sign PDF documents
• Support to read PDFs out loud
• Play audios and videos in PDF.
• Scan, capture, and convert paper documents to PDFs.
• Print PDFs
```

And I personally have been using it for long time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are willing to spend money for it. But for $3.99 you can buy [ezPDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader), which supports embedded video playback.

There's a trial to download for free.